# Android application confirm if Internet facility is available or not?

Tags: android, http, networking

**Update: Basically i need to confirm whether my network is a private network or connected with outside world, i.e. to internet. For example I am on a WiFi network, but the router internet line is not attached. So though network is connected, but Internet is not available.**

Need to show network details in my Android application,

- (a) whether n/w is available or not
- (b) Internet facility is available or not

Currently, i assume that www.google.com would always be up and below peice of code just works fine. But this solution is SLOW and based on assumption that www.google.com would always be up.

***Is there any better alternative to confirm if Internet facility is available on network or not?***

```
public static boolean isConnected(Context context){
        NetworkInfo info = Connectivity.getNetworkInfo(context);
        return (info != null && info.isConnected());
    }

public boolean checkInternetConnectivity() {

        try {
            HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(
                    "http://www.google.com").openConnection());
            urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Test");
            urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
            urlc.setConnectTimeout(3000);
            urlc.setReadTimeout(4000);
            urlc.connect();
            isInterNetAvailable = true;
            return (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            isInterNetAvailable = false;
            return (false);
        }
    }
public String getNWConnectivityText() {
    if (isConnected(getSherlockActivity()) == true) {

        if (true == checkInternetConnectivity()) {
            return ""N/W is connected and Internet is working!";
        } else {
            return "N/W is connected but Internet is NOT working!";
        }

    } else {
        return "N/W is not connected!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static boolean isConnected(Context context) {
    final ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final NetworkInfo activeNetwork = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Add to Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Update: Basically i need to confirm whether my network is a private network or connected with outside world, i.e. to internet. For example I am on a WiFi network, but the router internet line is not attached. So though network is connected, but Internet is not available. So will your solution work?

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to check for internet connectivity from your Activity

```
public boolean isInternetConnected() {
        ConnectivityManager cManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = cManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if(networkInfo == null)
            return false;
        else if(!networkInfo.isConnected())
            return false;
        else if(!networkInfo.isAvailable())
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
```

Also, add these permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: Update: Basically i need to confirm whether my network is a private network or connected with outside world, i.e. to internet. For example I am on a WiFi network, but the router internet line is not attached. So though network is connected, but Internet is not available. So will your solution work?

Answer (score 0):

I actually always use this ConnectionController class. It checks for both **WiFi** and **Mobile Connection**.

```
public class ConnectionController {

    /** NEEDS PERMISSIONS NETWORK AND WIFI STATE */

    /**
     * checks if a mobile or wifi connection is available or about to be available
     * sends a proper response for user information
     * @param context
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean isConnected(Context context) {

        if(context != null) {

            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo netinfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

            if (netinfo != null && netinfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
                android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
                android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

                if((mobile != null && mobile.isConnectedOrConnecting()) || (wifi != null && wifi.isConnectedOrConnecting())) return true;
                else return false;
            } else
                return false;
        } else return false;
    }
}
```

In code, you can check your connection like this:

```
if(ConnectionController.isConnected(Context)) {
    // do something if connection available
}
```

Comment: Update: Basically i need to confirm whether my network is a private network or connected with outside world, i.e. to internet. For example I am on a WiFi network, but the router internet line is not attached. So though network is connected, but Internet is not available.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to check internet connectivity

```
public boolean isConnectingToInternet(){
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
          if (connectivity != null) 
          {
              NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
              if (info != null) 
                  for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) 
                      if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                      {
                          return true;
                      }

          }
          return false;
    }
```

Also include following permissions in the Manifest file :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Update: Basically i need to confirm whether my network is a private network or connected with outside world, i.e. to internet. For example I am on a WiFi network, but the router internet line is not attached. So though network is connected, but Internet is not available. So will your solution work?

Comment: In that case you can use connectivity.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) instead of connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo() and store the result of info.isconnected() in boolean variable. Check the result and you will get the answer.